# d3.js - How can I set the cursor to hand when mouseover these elements on SVG container?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, mouseover

I have used d3.js to draw some circles on an SVG container.

I have successfully set the mouseover behavior on these circles to print simple console messages. I see those console messages when I mouseover (and mouseout) so I know they are working properly.

However, instead of printing that console messages, I want to change the cursor to the hand when I mouseover them, and I want to change the cursor back to the normal arrow when I mouse out. Given my code below, how can I do it?

On mouseover, I know I need to change the style property `cursor` to `pointer` and on mouseout, I know I need to change it to `default` but I don't know the syntax of how I should do it. Can someone please explain it to me? Below is my code.

```
        var myCircle = svgContainer.selectAll(".dots")
          .data(myDataList).enter().append("circle")
          .attr("class", "dots")
          .attr("cx", function(d, i) {return d.centerX})
          .attr("cy", function(d, i) {return d.centerY})
          .attr("r", 5)
          .attr("stroke-width", 0)
          .attr("fill", function(d, i) {return "red"})
          .style("display", "block");



        myCircle.on({
            "mouseover": function(d) {
              console.log('Hello World!'); // What do I change this to?
            },
            "mouseout": function(d) {
              console.log('Goodbye World!'); // What do I change this to?
            }
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
myCircle.on({
      "mouseover": function(d) {
        d3.select(this).style("cursor", "pointer"); 
      },
      "mouseout": function(d) {
        d3.select(this).style("cursor", "default"); 
      }
    });
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/gtbhz7nL/)

OR

you can simply work this out in the CSS.

`myCircle.style('cursor', 'pointer')`

Comment: You really don't need to set the style on mouseout. The reason is that if the mouse is over the element, the cursor style is applied. Otherwise, it's not. So there is no reason to set the style dynamically in this case. You might as well just set the style on initialization.

Comment: @Doughy what you saying is right. I wrote the answer specific to what the OP is asking. He wanted to know how to do it with `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: This is not a good answer. See below answer using CSS. Preferably, you can just set `myCircle.style('cursor', 'pointer')`.

Answer (score 30):

Why don't you simply let CSS handle it?

```
.dots {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Clearly the best solution, unless you need the cursor style to change based on some other variable in your code.

Answer (score 15):

Did you just try this :

```
    var myCircle = svgContainer.selectAll(".dots")
      .data(myDataList).enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dots")
      .attr("cx", function(d, i) {return d.centerX})
      .attr("cy", function(d, i) {return d.centerY})
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("stroke-width", 0)
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {return "red"})
      .style("display", "block")
      .style("cursor", "pointer");
```

Because when you define cursor as a pointer for your object, when you "mouseover", then the pointer become a pointer.

See here an example : https://jsfiddle.net/oj5vubxn/2/

Answer (score 15):

Setting the style dynamically in this case doesn't make any sense. If the mouse is over the element, the cursor style is applied. Otherwise, you are hovering over another element and the cursor style for that element is applied. So there is no reason to set the style dynamically based on mouseover events. You might as well just set the style on initialization.

```
myCircle.style("cursor", "pointer");
```

Or, just set the style in the CSS file as another answer indicated.

Comment: This is the best answer in the D3 paradigm.